# Amazon WorkDocs - API for document download

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-workdocs

With the Amazon WorkDocs API [1] I can list folders and files, create and delete folders, upload and delete files. But it seems there is no way to download a file.

The GetDocument API [2] returns a JSON document which includes a 'DownloadUrl' element but it is always 'null'. Also this 'DownloadUrl' element is not exposed in the SDK. I'm using the C++ SDK.

Is this by design?

[1] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/workdocs/latest/APIReference/Welcome.html

[2] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/workdocs/latest/APIReference/API_GetDocument.html

Comment: To get document's download url, have your tried [GetDocumentVersion](http://sdk.amazonaws.com/cpp/api/LATEST/class_aws_1_1_work_docs_1_1_work_docs_client.html#abe3df96168108059ab57535235ae9137).GetMetadata().GetSource(DocumentSourceType.ORIGINAL) ?

Comment: @amitd it has to explicitly request the source field otherwise it returns null. See the example shared by smac2020.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of how to download a document from Amazon WorkDocs using the API. This example is implemented in Java; however, it shows you how to perform this task. As you see, an URL object plays a role in downloading the document.

https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/master/javav2/example_code/workdocs/src/main/java/com/example/workdocs/DownloadUserDoc.java